# How to update RowList partially in brightscript

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm using RowList for vertically scrollable contents. In that I need to update only a specific row in the list. Is it possible?

Comment: it is, but please show how you're using RowList (show some code), that will help refine this into a clear question that will have lasting value on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The RowList has the following structure with respect to the ContentNodes it uses. It must have 1 content node as the root node. Next, you must have (as children of the root node) 1 content node for each row that you will have. Each of those rows is supposed to have 1 content node for each item that will appear in the row. So, it will look something like this.

```
<ContentNode> Root
    <ContentNode> 'Row 1
        <ContentNode></ContentNode> Row 1 Item 1
        <ContentNode></ContentNode> Row 1 Item 2
    </ContentNode>
    <ContentNode> Row 2
        <ContentNode></ContentNode> Row 2 Item 1
        <ContentNode></ContentNode> Row 2 Item 2
    </ContentNode>
</ContentNode>
```

If you want to update a specific row, you need to find the node for that row and replace it's children. [Here](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifSGNodeChildren) are the functions you can use on the children of nodes.